# scope developing / how to change scope result inside perform_action

Tags: ubuntu-touch, development, scopes

I became bit lost with how to set a result attribute or trigger scope search (refresh) inside `Scope::perform_action` method or in methods of  `ActivationQuery` object. The idea is to change data in a source, then either refresh a reply by new query or just modify previous result in same way as source has been changed. Typical example would be "was read" status set.

Could you help out a little with below example?

```
sc::ActivationQueryBase::UPtr Scope::perform_action(const sc::Result &result,
                                      sc::ActionMetadata const &metadata,
                                      std::string const &widget_id, std::string const &action_id) {

    //update current Result/reply or trigger new search by scope

    return sc::ActivationQueryBase::UPtr(new ActivationQuery(result, metadata, widget_id, action_id, config_));

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot change Result itself, it's received for reading only, you need to apply any updates to your backend data and then re-execute search. To do that, reimplement activate() method of your ActivationQueryBase in your ActivationQuery class; do whatever you need to update backend data in activate(), and then return ActivationResponse instance created with this ctor:

ActivationResponse(CannedQuery const& query);

The query argument should point to you scope.

An alternative approach for re-executing the search when a button in the preview is tapped is to set the uri attribute of the button with a value of CannedQuery::to_uri(), but in that case your activation handler is not executed.

Note, with the first approach you are likely to experience https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/unity8/+bug/1335761

I hope that helps.

Comment: thank you for the hint. I put
            sc::CannedQuery query("untitled.dev_test");
            query.set_query_string("");
            return sc::ActivationResponse(query);

into activate() method. it supposed to work, but query was not iniated.

Comment: btw, I made query string not empty and got query running when i manually return to the result list. So technically it is kind of working, but with a bug 1335761 and visible query string while i just need simple empty update. Let's see how to get it working.